# How do I link an existing install of GDAL to FileGDB in Linux?

Tags: gdal, esri-geodatabase, centos, elgis

The distribution I use (CentOS) only has GDAL 1.8 available through [elgis](http://elgis.argeo.org/). I've downloaded the FileGDB API from ESRI and I'd like to be able to link it after an install. How can I do this?